# Exclude strings of pattern "abba"

Tags: regex

For example, I want to exclude 'fitting', 'hollow', 'trillion'
but not 'hello' or 'pattern'

I already got the following to work

```
(.)(.)\2\1
```

which matches 'hollow' or 'fitting', but I have trouble negating this.

the closest thing I get is

```
^.(?!(.)(.)\2\1)
```

which excludes 'fitting' and 'hollow' but not 'trillion'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a little different from what you have. Your current regex will check for the pallindromicity (?) as of the second character. Since you want to check the whole string, you need to change it a little to:

```
^(?!.*(.)(.)\2\1)
```

The first anchor will ensure that the check is made only at the beginning (otherwise, the regex can claim a match at the end of the string).

Then the `.*` within the negative lookahead will enable the check to be done anywhere within the string. If there's any match, fail the entire match.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't match with trillion because you added `^.` means it must have a character before the match from beginning. For your first two cases it has `h` and `f` character. So if you change this into `^..(?!(.)(.)\2\1)` then it will work for `trillion`.

So in general the regex will be:

```
(?!.*(.)(.)\2\1)
   ^^ any number of characters(other than \n)
```